# Fast distance calculation for Starcraft2 bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am coding a bot for Starcraft 2, in which many distances have to be calculated every frame.

Here is the part of the library that is being used and I want to improve: https://github.com/Dentosal/python-sc2/blob/develop/sc2/position.py

I built a new class `Points` that inherits from `np.ndarray`.
It is not yet connected to the rest of the library, but the functions are done. I removed the functions `furthest_to`, `further_than` and so on because the `closer`-versions are basically the same execpt a `-1` or `<`.

Are these functions implemented in most efficient way? Is there a way to improve the parts that look like this:

`find = np.where(np.any(M < distance, axis=1))
selection = np.array([self[i] for i in find[0]])`

Any other comments or suggestions are also welcome :)

```
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional, Set, Tuple, Union  # for mypy type checking

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

from position import Point2


class Points(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, units_or_points):
        obj = np.asarray(units_or_points).view(cls)
        return obj

    def closest_to(self, point: Point2) -> Point2:
        """Returns the point of self that is closest to another point."""
        if point in self:
            return Point2(tuple(point))
        deltas = self - point
        distances = np.einsum("ij,ij->i", deltas, deltas)
        result = self[np.argmin(distances)]
        return Point2(tuple(result))

    def closer_than(self, point: Point2, distance: Union[int, float]) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with all points of self that
        are closer than distance to point."""
        position = np.array([point])
        M = cdist(self, position)
        find = np.where(np.all(M < distance, axis=1))
        selection = np.array([self[i] for i in find[0]])
        return Points(selection)

    def in_distance_between(
        self, point: Point2, distance1: Union[int, float], distance2: Union[int, float]
    ) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with all points of self
        that are between distance1 and distance2 away from point."""
        p = np.array([point])
        M = cdist(self, p)
        find = np.where(np.any(np.logical_and(distance1 < M, M < distance2), axis=1))
        selection = np.array([self[i] for i in find[0]])
        return Points(selection)

    def sort_by_distance_to(self, point: Point2, reverse: bool = False) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with all points of self sorted by distance to point.
        Ordered from smallest to biggest distance. Reverse order with keyword reverse=True."""
        deltas = self - point
        distances = (1 if reverse else -1) * np.einsum("ij,ij->i", deltas, deltas)
        result = self[distances.argsort()[::-1]]
        return Points(result)

    def closest_n_points(self, point: Point2, n: int) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with the n points of self that are closest to point."""
        deltas = self - point
        distances = np.einsum("ij,ij->i", deltas, deltas)
        result = (self[distances.argsort()[::-1]])[-n:]
        return Points(result)

    def in_distance_of_points(self, points: "Points", distance: Union[int, float]) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with every point of self that
        is in distance of any point in points."""
        M = cdist(self, points)
        find = np.where(np.any(M < distance, axis=1))
        selection = np.array([self[i] for i in find[0]])
        return Points(selection)

    def n_closest_to_distance(self, point: Point2, distance: Union[int, float], n: int) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with the n points of self
        which calculated distance to point is closest to distance."""
        deltas = self - point
        distances = np.absolute(distance - np.einsum("ij,ij->i", deltas, deltas))
        result = (self[distances.argsort()[::-1]])[-n:]
        return Points(result)
```

Comment: What is a typical size for `Points`, so that timings are meaningful?

Comment: Not all of above functions are currently in the library.I tracked size of the calls for a single game for the function closest:
`average n of 'closest' call: 13.8`
`min n of 'closest' call: 2`
`max n of 'closest' call: 128`
So i think if you test with up to 300 for a really late game situation with both players maxed out, it would make a meaningful test.

Comment: Also, what is `Point2`. Is it also a subclass of `numpy.ndarray` (since it seems to support subtraction)?

Comment: You can see it in the link I provided. It is just an object with x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably have another look at the [`scipy.spatial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html) module. It provides (hopefully) faster methods for most of these checks using a [k-d-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

class Points(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, units_or_points):
        obj = np.asarray(units_or_points).view(cls)
        obj.kd_tree = cKDTree(obj)
        return obj

    def closest_to(self, point: Point2) -> Point2:
        """Returns the point of self that is closest to another point."""
        _, i = self.kd_tree.query([[point.x, point.y]])
        return Point2(self[i][0])

    def closer_than(self, point: Point2, distance: Union[int, float]) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with all points of self that
        are closer than distance to point."""
        selection = self.kd_tree.query_ball_point([point.x, point.y], distance)
        return self[selection]

    def in_distance_between(
        self, point: Point2, distance1: Union[int, float], distance2: Union[int, float]
    ) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with all points of self
        that are between distance1 and distance2 away from point."""
        selection_close = self.kd_tree.query_ball_point([point.x, point.y], distance1)
        selection_far = self.kd_tree.query_ball_point([point.x, point.y], distance2)
        selection = list(set(selection_far) - set(selection_close))
        return self[selection]

    def closest_n_points(self, point: Point2, n: int) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with the n points of self that are closest to point."""
        _, indices = self.kd_tree.query([[point.x, point.y]], k=n)
        return self[indices]

    def in_distance_of_points(self, points: "Points", distance: Union[int, float]) -> "Points":
        """Returns a new Points object with every point of self that
        is in distance of any point in points."""
        pairs = self.kd_tree.query_ball_tree(points.kd_tree, distance)
        return points[[i for closest in pairs for i in closest]]
```

These are all the ones I could quickly find a way for using the tree. Not included are `sort_by_distance_to`, `n_closest_to_distance` and `n_closest_to_distance`.

In order to test if this is really faster, here are some tests, with the following setup:

```
np.random.seed(42)
points = np.random.rand(300, 2)
points_graipher = Points(points)
points_op = PointsOP(points)
point = Point2(np.random.rand(2))
points2 = np.random.rand(10, 2)
points2_graipher = Points(points2)
```

Here `PointsOP` is you class and `Points` is the class defined in this answer.

```
%timeit points_op.closest_to(point)
# 38.3 µs ± 1.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit points_graipher.closest_to(point)
# 43.7 µs ± 249 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit points_op.closer_than(point, 0.1)
# 39.5 µs ± 238 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)    
%timeit points_graipher.closer_than(point, 0.1)
# 11 µs ± 26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit points_op.in_distance_between(point, 0.1, 0.2)
# 52.9 µs ± 275 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit points_graipher.in_distance_between(point, 0.1, 0.2)
# 21.9 µs ± 180 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit points_op.closest_n_points(point, 10)
# 29.5 µs ± 359 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit points_graipher.closest_n_points(point, 10)
# 41.7 µs ± 287 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit points_op.in_distance_of_points(points2, 0.1)
# 116 µs ± 727 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit points_graipher.in_distance_of_points(points2_graipher, 0.1)
# 89.2 µs ± 500 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As you can see for \$N = 300\$ points there are some methods which are faster with the KDTree (up to four times), some that are basically the same and some that are slower (by up to two times).

To get a feeling how the different approaches, scale, here are some plots. The only thing changing is the number of points. The steps are `30, 300, 3000, 30000`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

To summarize, you should check this for some actual cases you have. Depending on the size of points your implementation or this implementation is faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the first comment i said n around 300 will be the highest values, most n will be at 20 or so.

Comment: @Tweakimp: Yes, which is why I took 300 as the first case. The larger case was mostly to see if and when the KDTree becomes much better. Will add some plots including also some lower numbers.

Comment: @Tweakimp: Added those plots.

Comment: Thank you for all the work you put into this. :) Interesting to see how closest n points  is constant...

Comment: @Tweakimp: Yeah, I was a bit surprised by this as well. Apparently those cuts in the tree are very efficient :)